# How can I tell Bison I also expect reduce-reduce conflicts?

Tags: parsing, grammar, yacc, bison

My C#-ish toy grammar now has its first reduce-reduce conflicts! I'm so proud of me.

It seems all right to me, however (I switched off to a GLR parser for the occasion). The problem is, while I know the `%expect` directive can shut up Bison about shift/reduce conflicts, I can't find the equivalent for reduce/reduce conflicts. So what should I use to make it silent about my 3 shift/reduces and my 2 reduce/reduces?

Comment: If you can, grab the Dragon book "Compilers: Principles, Tools & Techniques" by Aho et al and "Modern Compiler Implementation in C"

Comment: Well, the Dragon Book's kind of expensive for my poor student status. :/ Especially since I'm doing it purely as a hobby, and I certainly won't have classes about compilers before several years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the GNU Bison documentation, [found here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Expect-Decl.html)

> For normal LALR(1) parsers,
>   reduce/reduce conflicts are more
>   serious, and should be eliminated
>   entirely. Bison will always report
>   reduce/reduce conflicts for these
>   parsers. With GLR parsers, however,
>   both kinds of conflicts are routine;
>   otherwise, there would be no need to
>   use GLR parsing. Therefore, it is also
>   possible to specify an expected number
>   of reduce/reduce conflicts in GLR
>   parsers, using the declaration:
>
> ```
>  %expect-rr n
> ```

Comment: Aww, dammit. My googlefu led me to http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_6.html#SEC54 instead, where no mention of this was made. Thanks.